# Unable to update parent functions variable from inside $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to push a value that is being returned inside the ajax call to an array outside of the call, but still inside the parent function.  It seems that I am not able to access any variable and update it from inside the ajax success statement.  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
     var bill = [];
     var billDate = [];
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: '../Js/readData.php',
         data: "",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data)
         {
           //var obj=JSON.parse(data);
           var obj=data;
           for (var x in obj)
             {
               bill.push(obj[x].Amount);
               billDate.push(obj[x].Dates);
             }
         }
      });
```

Comment: Did you try to console.log Amount/Dates inside for-loop?

Comment: `for (var x in obj) {  ...obj[x]...  }` is almost certainly not correct. Do you mean to use just `x` there?

Answer (score 1):

The ajax call is `asynchronous` so the variables are not updated immediately for availability outside of the success function.  It is called after the time involved with loading the data from the server.

You may want to move the anonymous success function to an external function and do whatever handling you need in there.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: '../Js/readData.php',
   data: "",
   dataType: 'json',
   success: mySuccessFunction
});

var mySuccessFunction = function(obj) {
     for (var x in obj)
       {
         bill.push(obj[x].Amount);
         billDate.push(obj[x].Dates);
       }  
}
```

Comment: Another alternative, though less desirable would be to set async off in the ajax call: async: false.